# Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 192.168.1.55; nested exception is:

Tags: java, exception

i run this code in my system and i don't weather to write localaddress(localhost) or remote addres(IP address)...

```
ref= (RMISIntf)Naming.lookup("rmi://"+"192.168.0.15"+"/RMIServer");
```

and also i try this code also till i get no response

```
 ref= (RMISIntf)Naming.lookup("rmi://"+"localhost"+":"+8033+"/RMIServer");
 //MyRemoteObject ro = (MyRemoteObject) Naming.lookup("//" + "localhost" + ":" + port + "/" + name);
    //ref=Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:8080/RmiServer",RMISIntf);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is good to test first with the localhost as it is easy and does not require to set rules as is with the remote connection i.e. the external address.

The [Java RMI faq](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/faq.html#domain) says,

> The appropriate workaround is to set the system property
>   java.rmi.server.hostname when starting the server. The value of the
>   property should be the externally reachable hostname (or IP address)
>   of the server -- whatever works when specified as the host-part in
>   Naming.lookup is good enough.

Also just have a look at the properties for remote method invocation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/javarmiproperties.html).

Comment: i start the rmiregisrty before executing this  program  still i get the error....

Comment: @user2293819 This answer is correct. +1. If you hadn't started the RMI Registry your server would have failed and you wouldn't even have got this far. It isn't relevant. 'localhost' isn't an appropriate setting for a value that needs to be understood by a client. You need to set it to an IP address of the server host that is accessible by the client.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make it work using any of the two, but keep in mind that for it to work with the external address, you may need to create some rules on your firewall and forwarding on your modem.